# QT 5.10.1 Serial-Port not sending, why?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, serial-port

There is no error while compiling and running the Binary as root!
But on the receiving set is no signal, why?
I've testet both connections:

- real USB-RS232 - Adapter QString portName = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
- Host-Pipe to VirtualBox QString portName = "/dev/Winsock";

If somebody would help me, my code is here:

https://github.com/KarmaMan1982/QTSerialSender

Comment: Why does your class that inherits from QSerialPort have another QSerialPort as a member of the class?

Comment: @KarmaMan82 please put relevant code in the question instead of linking to a repository that is not guaranteed to exist in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your business logic, which is everything included between

```
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
```

and

```
return a.exec();
```

but excluding those lines won't do what you want.
This should be part of a slot in a class that extends QObject. This slot would have to be invoked by any mean (for instance, a QTimer) when the application runs.

QSerialPort doesn't do anything before a.exec() is called.